# program is listening on TCP port, but connections to that port are refused

Tags: c#, tcp, listener

I have a simple program I'm developing to perform some bandwidth tests on remote computers my company controls at our client sites. One copy of the program goes on a remote computer and is told to listen on a specified port. Another copy of the same program is then told to connect to the listening computer, then send a serialized object with a message of known length, random contents. The transfer is timed and the results sent back to the originating machine.

It works fine over the loopback interface; two copies of the program going, one listening on a part, the other connecting to that same port (in a shared manner) and sending the data. However, when I move the "remote" side of this test to a different test machine on the same intranet, even though the program says it's "listening" for its connection, the port cannot be connected to by the program on my dev machine. I get the standard error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".

There are no active firewalls between these two computers, including Windows Firewall. I can create other types of remote connections such as VNC.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

Listening for a connection:

```
    public void BeginListeningAsServer()
    {
        if (Listener != null) Listener.Stop();
        if (ListenerThread != null) ListenerThread.Join();
        Listener = new TcpListener(RemoteAddress, RemotePort);
        Listener.Start();
        Listening = true;
        ListenerThread = new Thread(ListenForConnections);
        ListenerThread.Start();
    }

    private void ListenForConnections()
    {
        while (Listening)
        {
            if (Listener.Pending())
                Listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(HandleIncomingClient, null);
        }
    }

    private void HandleIncomingClient(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var client = Listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
        var thread = new Thread(c => HandleIncomingClientMessage((TcpClient)c));
        HandlerThreads.Add(thread);
        Clients.Add(client);
        thread.Start(client);
    }
```

Connecting to this listening program:

```
    public void ConnectAsClient()
    {
        var client = new TcpClient();
        client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        client.Connect(RemoteAddress, RemotePort); //this line fails
        Clients.Add(client);
    }
```

Comment: Which port number are you using?

Comment: What address has your app bound to? If it's listening to (using 1234 for example purposes) `127.0.0.1:1234`, then external connections will get the "connection refused" error. It'd need to be listening to the machine's actual `IP:1234` combo, or to `*:1234` to listen to ALL addresses.

Comment: Have you tried using telnet to connect to the remote computer?  You could use the `telnet remoteComputer 29342` from the command prompt where 29342 is the port you're trying to connect to.  If you're able to connect with telnet, that would at least tell you that the problem is in your client app.  If you're not able to connect with telnet, the problem is either in your server app, or (more likely) a network issue (like a firewall you're not aware of).

Comment: I'd to second the telnet recommendation. Telnet is _the_ tool for using divide and conquer to solve these kinds of issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you star your listener is a bit off. You don't need to specify the **Address**, only the port.

Comment: The constructor with only the port is marked as deprecated in .NET 4.0. But, I'll give it a try.

Comment: There is an address in the IPAddress class, I think, that is IPAddress.Any.

Comment: Yeah, you need IPAddress.Any.  If you try to use local, like 127.0.0.1, then you may not be listening on the adapter exposed to the internet, and the behavior you'll see is that you can connect locally on your machine, but you won't be able to connect from a machine on the internet.

Comment: Well, it worked. I think it had to do with trying to use the loopback address when referring to the local computer; telling the program, in effect, to figure the IP address out for itself worked like a charm.